# Help identifying a small (1.6 x 1.2) IC on the output of a buck converter

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, dc-dc-converter, repair

I've done some looking but haven't been able to find a component that quite matches this one. It's on the output of a switching converter. The only markings on it are AG followed by a sideways F. The package is ~1.6mm x 1.2mm.

As a bit of background, I'm attempting to repair this circuit. After being led to that switcher by a thermal camera (output shorted to ground), I found that the pin from the switcher is shorting to ground across this component.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Circuit images showing component to identify]

Best guess I've come up with is this [MP62040DQFU](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP62040/document_id/1705) power switch. Pinout makes sense. AG on package lines up with active-low on the datasheet, which makes sense with a single resistor on the enable to pull it back down once a shutdown signal is gone. It's really just the bars and sideways F that are throwing me, since they aren't mentioned on the datasheet nor on their [package marking](https://media.monolithicpower.com/cms_document/Package%20Information/UTQFN-4%20(1.6mmX1.2mm)%20TOP%20MARKING.pdf?_ga=2.95072156.1043203339.1677684851-92507281.1677684851&_gl=1*ptrbqn*_ga*OTI1MDcyODEuMTY3NzY4NDg1MQ..*_ga_XNRPF6L9DD*MTY3NzY4NDg1MC4xLjEuMTY3NzY4NDg2Mi40OC4wLjA.) drawing

Comment: Vishay has load switches (e.g. SIP4282) with a similar packaging and a plausible pinout. They also have to two letter markings, but I wasn't able to find one with a leading A. Just in case it doesn't turn out to be the LDO @Velvel suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It possibly could be the [BU2JTA2WNVX](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/linear_regulator/buxxta2wnvx-e.pdf) 2.85V LDO regulator from ROHM.

Marking:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Pins/Signals:

[image]

Package size:

[image]

Comment: Looks promising, but from the layout it would seem pins 3 and 4 are reversed for it to make sense. Maybe a similar part.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Indeed, I would've been happier if pins 3 and 4 were reversed. But it's not entirely ruled out (yet). It all depends on where the pin 4 via connects to. *VIN* could be connected to one power supply, and *STBY* to another.

Comment: The resistors to the right could potentially be a voltage divider for an adjustable LDO.